# Some Microsoft Word review comments are displayed in a popup instead of in the Markup Area when viewing "Simple Markup"

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, comments, review

I am running Microsoft Word 2013. I received a Word document (docx format) that has a lot of review comments in it.

I am using the "Previous" and "Next" buttons on the Review tab to go through the comments, and I have "Simple Markup" selected. For most of the comments, when I click Previous/Next, a comment will be highlighted in the Markup Area on the right side, and the text in the document that the comment corresponds to will also be highlighted, like this:

[image]

However, there are a few comments where when I click on Next/Previous, nothing gets highlighted in the Markup Area, and instead a Comments popup box appears outside the Word window on one of my other monitors, like this:

[image]

When this happens, there is no text highlighted in the document, so I don't know what the comment is referring to.

The down arrow on the upper-right corner of the Comments popup only has Move, Size, and Close options. I tried moving the Comments popup on top of the Word document to see if it would be absorbed into the Markup Area, and that didn't happen.

But when I change "Simple Markup" to "All Markup", then all of those comments are correctly displayed in the Markup Area with pointers to the text in the document. How can I fix these comments so that they are displayed in the Markup Area with the rest of the comments when "Simple Markup" is selected?

Answer (score 0):

### I suspect that the comments where nothing is highlighted in the text were inserted without any text selected.

If you want someone to look at it, save a copy of the document on OneDrive or Dropbox. Remove any proprietary or confidential information and keep it short. Post a display link in your question.

Comment: I just tested that by adding a comment to the document without selecting any text. The comment still appears in the Markup Area, and it points to the spot in the document where the cursor happened to be.

Comment: You can edit your question to include a sample document.